# improving reflection code mentioned in the post?

Tags: java, reflection, java-ee-7

I am new to Generics and Reflection. Could you please tell me how can i improve below code?

```
public static <T extends SomeObject> T returnObject(Class<T> classOfT, SomeClass data) throws SomeException
{

T object= null; 
Class[] signature = new Class[] {SomeClass.class};
        Object[] args = new Object[] {data};
Constructor<T> objectConstructor = classOfT.getDeclaredConstructor(signature);
object= (T)objectConstructor.newInstance(args);

}
```

Also,  `Class[] signature = new Class[] {SomeClass.class};` here i have only one SomeClass.class. In this case does it really necessary to take Class[] ?  Can i avoid using Class[] array and use Class alone?

Comment: Richard, here do i really need Class[] ?

Answer (score 1):

Without testing, you could try the following:

```
public static <T extends SomeObject> T returnObject(Class<T> classOfT, SomeClass data) throws SomeException{
    return classOfT.getDeclaredConstructor(SomeClass.class).newInstance(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor` takes [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), according to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29), so you do not need to explicitly create an array. You can just call it like this:

```
Constructor<T> objectConstructor =
    classOfT.getDeclaredConstructor(SomeClass.class);
```

Likewise, `Constructor.newInstance` takes varargs, so again you do not need to pass an array explicitly. The cast to `T` is also unnecessary:

```
object = objectConstructor.newInstance(args);
```

So, you can call it as Puce showed in his answer.